# How to notify List component that one item has changed the size?

Tags: react-virtualized

I would like to render a list of items using react-virtualized, however some of the items could change the size.

I have added a demo, where each item has a button and when someone clicks the button then the item needs to expand and push the below items lower:
https://plnkr.co/edit/GG2bSIC5M1Gj7BR1pOii

The use case is similar to facebook posts, when someone comments it will expand the post and push the other posts lower.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<List
className='List'
autoHeight
width={300}
height={400}
rowCount={list.length}
rowHeight={30}
rowRenderer={
  ({ index, isScrolling, key, style }) => (
    <div
      className='Row'
      key={key}
      style={style}
    >
      {list[index]}
      <Expander />  /* contains the button, which when click it will expand more text*/
    </div>
  )
}
/>,
document.getElementById('example')
```

Is any way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I am realizing that there must be a way to force the `List` to update items and recalculate positions. There is an example with `InfiniteLoader` ([react-virtualized example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.example.js)) which is using `registerChild` in the List as a ref. And it seems that when InfiniteLoader receives answer from the server it capable of forcing list to re-render rows.

I have tried another example with `forceUpdate` on list, however the List is still not updating.

https://plnkr.co/edit/RftoShEkQW5MR5Rl28Vu

Comment: You need to use the `List.recomputeRowHeights` method. https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md#recomputerowheights-index-number

Comment: @TomCoughlin Hi, where and how do I call `recomputeRowHeights` or `forceUpdateGrid()` in a functional component?

Answer (score 4):

As per the Documentation forceUpdateGrid() should be called instead of forceUpdate().

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md#public-methods

I faced the similar issue and solved it by calling forceUpdateGrid() inside componentWillReceiveProps method.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(){
    this.refs.forceUpdateGrid();
}

render(){
    <List
        ref={ref => this.refs = ref}
        .....
    />
}
```

Comment: Hi, how do I call `forceUpdateGrid()` in a functional component?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Collection from react-virtualized instead of List. It should help :)

Comment: Could you add a plunker example? ( or modify my existing plunker and add the link).

Answer (score 1):

add `key={Math.random()}` the parent of the list item solved my issue.

```
<ListWidget key={Math.random()}>
  <Autosizer>{
     .....
     <List
      .....
      />
    .....
   }</Autosizer>
</ListWidget>
```

Note: not recommended, it's just a workaround to get PR accepted

Comment: Thank you a million ! I spent many days trying to solve that